# Python dataframe rank series

Tags: python, dataframe

What I have is a dataframe with over 2 columns like this

```
columnA columnB
    1      a
    1      b
    1      c
    2      d
```

I just want to rank columnA like this

```
columnA columnB rankA
    1      a      1
    1      b      2
    1      c      3
    2      d      1
```

So what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df['rankA'] = df.groupby('columnA').cumcount() + 1
print (df)
   columnA columnB  rankA
0        1       a      1
1        1       b      2
2        1       c      3
3        2       d      1
```